# How to colorize one chip in v-autocomplete (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, colors, vuetify.js, styling, v-autocomplete

I would like a selected chip that meets certain criteria to have a different color than all others. How can i do that in Vuetify? Mayby something else than v-autocomplete would be better? I am using Vuetify 2.0

```
  <v-autocomplete
    :value="value"
    :items="usersItems"
    :loading="isLoadingData"
    :search-input.sync="searchUsers"
    outlined
    chips
    small-chips
    deletable-chips
    clearable
    item-text="full_name"
    :item-value="getValueWrapper"
    label="Użytkownicy"
    placeholder="Wpisz by wyszukać"
    multiple
    @input="handleInput"
    @change="$emit('change', value)"
  >
    <template #prepend-item>
      <v-list-item
        @click="addAllUsers"
      >
        <v-list-item-action>
          <v-icon color="primary">
            mdi-plus
          </v-icon>
        </v-list-item-action>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>
            {{ $t('users_picker.add_all') }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider class="mt-2" />
    </template>
    <template #item="data">
      <template v-if="typeof data.item !== 'object'">
        <v-list-item-content v-t4ext="data.item" />
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <img
            v-if="data.item.avatar_public_path"
            :src="data.item.avatar_public_path"
          >
          <v-icon v-else>
            mdi-account-circle
          </v-icon>
        </v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title v-html="data.item.full_name" />
          <v-list-item-subtitle>
            {{ data.item.email }}
          </v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </template>
    </template>
  </v-autocomplete>
```

Thanks for any help :) I described what i expect to happen on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [chip v-slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#slots-chip) and provide your own custom chip content for *all* chips, but then [bind a class](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) based on whatever conditions you want. The classname can then alter the styling of the chips that meet your conditions.

In this minimal example, a chip for a selected object with property `name` having value `"Britta Holt"` will be colored red:

### Vuetify 3

```html
<v-autocomplete chips :items="people" v-model="selection" >
  <template v-slot:chip="{ props, item }">
    <v-chip
      :class="{ customChip: item.raw.name === 'Britta Holt' }"
      v-bind="props"
      :text="item.raw.name"
    ></v-chip>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    selection: [],
    people: [
      { name: 'Britta Holt' },
      { name: 'Jane Smith ' },
      { name: 'John Smith' },
    ],
  }
}
```

```css
<style>
  .customChip {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
</style>
```

[Vuetify Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

### Vuetify 2

The concept is the same, but the slot is different.  Use [selection](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#slots-selection) slot instead

```html
<template v-slot:selection="data">
  <v-chip
    :class="{ customChip: data.item.name === 'Britta Holt' }"
    v-bind="data.attrs"
    :input-value="data.selected"
  >
    {{ data.item.name }}
  </v-chip>
</template>
```

[Vuetify 2 codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/VwVBqRP?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you. It is very good answer, but problem lays in that i am using Vuetify 2.0, not 3.0. I forgot to mention that, sorry. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: No problem, vuetify 2 is very similar.  The solution with either version is nearly the same, just a difference in slot.  I've updated my answer with Vuetify 2 solution.